# How to remove duplicate phrases from a document?

Tags: bash, text, nlp, duplicates

Is there a simple way to remove duplicate contents from a large textfile? It would be great to be able to detect duplicate sentences (as separated by "." or even better to find duplicates of sentence fragments (such as 4-word pieces of text).

Answer (score 2):

Removing duplicate words is easy enough, as other people have pointed out.  Anything more complicated than that, and you're into [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) territory.  Bash isn't the best tool for that -- you need a slightly more elegant weapon for a civilized age.

Personally, I recommend [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and it's [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (natural language toolkit).  Before you dive into that, it's probably worth reading up a little bit on NLP so that you know what you actually need to do.  For example, the "4-word pieces of text" are known as 4-grams ([n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) in the generic case) in the literature.  The toolkit will help you find those, and more.

Of course, there are probably alternatives to Python/NLTK, but I'm not familiar with any.

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicate phrases an keeping the original order:

```
nl -w 8 "$infile" | sort -k2 -u | sort -n | cut -f2
```

The first stage of the pipeline prepends every line with line number to document the original order. The second stage sorts the original data with the unique switch set.
The third restores the original order (sorting the 1. column). The final cut removes the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate *lines* (which have to be *exactly* equal) with `uniq` if you `sort` your textfile first.

```
$ cat foo.txt
foo
bar
quux
foo
baz
bar
$ sort foo.txt
bar
bar
baz
foo
foo
quux
$ sort foo.txt | uniq
bar
baz
foo
quux
```

Apart from that, there's no *simple* way of doing what you want. (How will you even split sentences?)

Comment: You could run a set of sliding windows 1..i over the text, each i words long, and hash the contents. Each hash collision is a potential duplicate. You probably want to normalize whitespace and case differences (if you have these concepts in your language). It's not a major programming effort but still probably a day or two of work, if you think it's worth the time.

Comment: `awk '!a[$0]++'` is better than `sort | uniq` because a) it doesn't need to consume all the input before starting to produce output and b) it doesn't scramble your lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with backreferences.
If you write `grep "\([[:alpha:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\1" -o <filename>`  it will match any two identical words following one another. I.e. if the file content is `this is the the test file` , it will output `the the`.

(Explanation `[[:alpha:]]` matches any character a-z and A-Z, the asterisk `*` after it means that may appear as many times as it wants, the `\(\)` is used for grouping to backreference it later, then `[[:space:]]*` matches any number of spaces and tabs, and finally `\1` matches the exact sequence that was found, that was enclosed in `\(\)`brackets)

Likewise, if you want to match a group of 4 words, that is repeated two times in a row, the expression will look like `grep "\(\([[:alpha:]]*[[:space]]*\)\{4\}[[:space:]]*\1" -o <filename>` - it will match e.g. `a b c d a b c d`.

Now we need to add an arbitrary character sequence inbetween matches. In theory this should be done with inserting `.*` just before backreference, i.e. `grep "\(\([[:alpha:]]*[[:space]]*\)\{4\}.*\1" -o <filename>`, but this doesn't seem to work for me - it matches just any string and ignores said backreference

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there's no easy method. In general any solution needs to first decide how to split the input document into chunks (sentences, sets of 4 words each, etc) and then compare them to find duplicates. If it's important that the ordering of the non-duplicate elements by the same in the output as it was in the input then this only complicates matters further.

The simplest bash-friendly solution would be to split the input into lines based on whatever criteria you choose (e.g. split on each `.`, although doing this quote-safely is a bit tricky) and then use standard duplicate detection mechanisms (e.g. `| uniq -c | sort -n | sed -E -ne '/^[[:space:]]+1/!{s/^[[:space:]]+[0-9]+ //;p;}'` and then, for each resulting line, remote the text from the input.

Presuming that you had a file that was properly split into lines per "sentence" then

```
uniq -c lines_of_input_file | sort -n | sed -E -ne '/^[[:space:]]+1/!{s/^[[:space:]]+[0-9]+ //;p;}' | while IFS= read -r match ; do sed -i '' -e 's/'"$match"'//g' input_file ; done
```

Might be sufficient. Of course it will break horribly if the `$match` contains any data which `sed` interprets as a pattern. Another mechanism should be employed to perform the actual replacement if this is an issue for you.

Note: If you're using GNU sed the `-E` switch above should be changed to `-r`

Answer (score 0):

I just created a script in python, that does pretty much what I wanted originally:

```
import string
import sys

def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit("Usage: find_duplicate_fragments.py some_textfile.txt")
file=sys.argv[1]
infile=open(file,"r")
text=infile.read()
text=text.replace('\n','') # remove newlines
table = string.maketrans("","")
text=text.translate(table, string.punctuation) # remove punctuation characters
text=text.translate(table, string.digits) # remove numbers
text=text.upper() # to uppercase
while text.find("  ")>-1:
    text=text.replace("  "," ") # strip double-spaces

spaces=list(find_all(text," ")) # find all spaces

# scan through the whole text in packets of four words
# and check for multiple appearances.
for i in range(0,len(spaces)-4): 
    searchfor=text[spaces[i]+1:spaces[i+4]]
    duplist=list(find_all(text[spaces[i+4]:len(text)],searchfor))
    if len(duplist)>0:
        print len(duplist),': ',searchfor
```

BTW: I'm a python newbie, so any hints on better python practise are welcome!